# Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission)

Tags: android, permission-denied

Here are my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pa4ad.earthquakeviewer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Earthquake"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tested these code on a Nexus 7 1st generation, not an emulator. After a complete search online, I found solutions to similar questions and have added the permission INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, but still get this error.

```
 03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
    03-25 11:15:49.909: E/AndroidRuntime(27298):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:500)
```

Comment: I have deleted the app on Nexus 7 and re-install with the complete code above, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using an IDE, like Android Studio? The spelling error in `permission` should be highlighted for you.

Comment: Thank you. But I have "permission" corrected, app deleted and re-installed and I still get the same errors.

Comment: I use Eclipse Juno as the IDE, but there was no build errors caused by the misspelling of the "permission".

Comment: I copied the line with the incorrect spelling `permisson`  :)

Answer (score 12):

there is a spelling mistake in permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.INTERNET"/>
```

use this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: @Ahmed what do mean? is there any problem with my answer?

Comment: No. What I meant was I am surprised that the typo did not raise a build error for Anderson.

Comment: Thank you. But I have "permission" corrected, app deleted and re-installed and I still get the same errors.

Comment: @Anderson try cleaning UR project and re run

Answer (score 2):

grant internet permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```